# jenkins pass information to next build

Tags: jenkins

I've created a simple program that executes 'something' and records a number into a text file. And when the program runs again, it will check the text file and executes 'something' again and record a number to the text file.

So, as you can see the text file is working as a database. I didn't use any proper database because it only holds a number. In my local, this didn't cause any problem.

But when I try to apply this program to run in Jenkins every hour. The text file is deleted before every build, causing 'file not existing' error to this simple program.

To take care of this I have implemented shell command to copy the text file to another place in Jenkins after every execution and copying it back before the next execution starts.
When I first took care of this. It looked like it was working. But one day. I don't know why, but the text file which was copied to another place where thought to be a safe place was gone.

I've looked into a lot of Jenkins Plugins to take care of this. But still couldn't find any to solve my problem.

Comment: Your approach will only work if the build was run on the same worker.

Comment: Thank you @gaiazov for your comment. Yes, currently I am running on the same worker.
I've taken care of this by modifying the shell command slightly. Didn't have any perfect solution for this, yet.